# How do I change my mysql query to include rows for which the inner join cannot find a match?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

This is the query I'm currently using:

```
SELECT
q1.item AS q1item,q1.store AS q1store,q1.marion AS q1marion,
q1.carbondale AS q1carbondale,q2.marion AS q2marion,q2.carbondale AS q2carbondale
FROM jdgower_items q1
INNER JOIN jdgower_items q2 ON q1.item=q2.item
AND q1.store_id=q2.store_id AND DATE(q1.datetime) = DATE(NOW())
AND DATE(q2.datetime) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
WHERE q1.store_id='$the_main_store_id' OR q1.competitor_id='$the_main_store_id'
ORDER BY q1.item ASC,q1.competitor_id ASC,q1.store DESC,q1.store_id ASC
```

Basically the idea is to get one item per row, with today's price and yesterday's price...along with all of the competitors I'm tracking with their respective prices.  This gets me exactly what I want until I add a new competitor...if that competitor doesn't have an entry for yesterday, nothing returns for that competitor in the loop.  I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the INNER JOIN on the line "AND DATE(q2.datetime) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)" but I'm not sure how to remedy it.  Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What about using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`? This way, you will have some results with `NULL` for `q2` fields, but you'll have the rows.

Comment: Thank you for the response and I apologize for my ineptness...when I change 'inner' to 'left' it ends up pulling all rows, where I'd like to only pull today and yesterday.

Comment: I thought about:

`INNER JOIN jdgower_items q2
ON q1.item=q2.item
AND q1.store_id=q2.store_id
AND DATE(q1.datetime) = DATE(NOW())
LEFT JOIN DATE(q2.datetime) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

but that throws a syntax error.

Comment: oh I see. I didn't paid enought attention to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you seek try LEFT JOIN if yhat fail try RIGHT JOIN

Comment: LEFT JOIN ends up pulling all rows, RIGHT JOIN ends up pulling exactly the same as the INNER JOIN.  Thank you for your response.  Please let me know if I haven't provided enough info.